# How to modify or replace in PHP my SQL query containing "LIKE" and "bindValue" by CQL (Cassandra DataStax PHP DRIVER)?

Tags: php, cassandra, cql, datastax-php-driver

Looking for how to do a `LIKE` in a CQL query (using the following Cassandra PHP Driver: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) replacing my following SQL code:

```
    $con->execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images(siteUrl varchar PRIMARY KEY, imageUrl varchar, alt varchar, title varchar, description varchar, 
                    keywords varchar, textFromWebPage varchar, site_lang varchar, width_of_image float, height_of_image float, image_type varchar, 
                    image_extension varchar, image_attribute varchar, clicks bigint, broken int, centroidScore float, graphBasedScore float, scrapeScore float, 
                    centroidWeightedScore float, created_date timestamp) WITH caching='ALL';");
        
        $con->execute("CREATE CUSTOM INDEX images_prefix ON images(siteUrl, alt, title, keywords, description, textFromWebPage) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'");
        
    
        $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * 
                                        FROM images 
                                            WHERE (title LIKE :term 
                                            OR alt LIKE :term 
                                            OR siteUrl LIKE :term 
                                            OR keywords LIKE :term 
                                            OR description LIKE :term
                                            OR textFromWebPage LIKE :term
                                            AND broken=0 ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT :fromLimit, :pageSize");
        
                    $searchTerm = "%". $term . "%";
                    $query->bindValue(":term", $searchTerm);
                    $query->bindValue(":fromLimit", $fromLimit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query->bindValue(":pageSize", $pageSize, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query->execute();
        
                    $resultsHtml = "<div class='imageResults'>";
        
                    $count = 0;
                    
                    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                         ...
                         ...
                    }
```

I saw this on the following DataStax documentation link: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html, that it needs to do a `CREATE CUSTOM INDEX` to create a prefix on the Table concerned and specifying the column on which the `LIKE` request must be made.
**But in my case, I need to apply `LIKE` query to multiple column of `images` Table.**

***So how can I modify my Code above so that it adapts correctly to DataStax's CASSANDRA PHP Driver knowing that originally it was SQL that I am trying to replace with CQL and that it contains above all a `bindValue` ???***

Please help me out as this has been a headache for me for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

These lines don't need quotes, the string type PARAM binding will be enough (see below):

```
OR strcmp(soundex(title), soundex(:shorterm)) = 0
OR strcmp(soundex(alt), soundex(:shorterm)) = 0)
OR strcmp(soundex(siteUrl), soundex(:shorterm)) = 0
OR strcmp(soundex(keywords), soundex(:shorterm)) = 0
OR strcmp(soundex(description), soundex(:shorterm)) = 0
OR strcmp(soundex(description), soundex(:shorterm)) = 0
```

You have define the params as strings.

```
$query->bindValue(":term", $searchTerm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":shorterm", $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```